# How can I keep the execution permissions when cloning a repository in windows?

Tags: git, file-permissions, git-bash

I have a gitlab repo that contains several shell files and also what I think are executables. (I know built executables should better not be included in repos but I didn't build the repo) (oh and a mk file too)

When I git clone the repo from a linux machine and I do

```
ls the/path/I/am/interested -l
```

I can see that both sh files and also the executables have the x permission. (and the mk file too! although I don't know if mk files should)

However when I git clone the repo from a windows bash shell
(To clone it I did

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true  -c core.filemode=false therepo.git
```

and I do the same I got

- The sh files keep their x permissions
- The executable (and the mk file) lose the permissions.

I would like for all the files to keep their X permissions. What can I do?

For reference my git config has

```
core.autocrlf=input
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
core.editor=nano.exe

core.autocrlf=input
core.symlinks=true
core.filemode=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.symlinks=true
core.filemode=false
```

P.S. Is there a way to check permissions in the Gitlab repository itself?

Comment: Why did you include `-c core.filemode=false` in your clone command? (Related, though not to the chmod part, why did you include `-c core.symlinks=true` as well?)

Comment: the first one to keep the execution permissions. The second one to keep the symlinks (unrelated)

Comment: Note that Git probes the file system's symlink support at repository-creation time, the same way it probes the file system's chmod support. If the file system has symlinks, Git will set `core.symlinks=true` itself, and if not, it will set `core.symlinks=false`.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like for all the files to keep their X permissions. What can I do?

Probably not much, except perhaps to install and use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions) (or [Cygwin, but note that it does not play well with other NTFS users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146372/how-why-cygwin-breaks-windows-permissions)).  Be sure to use NFTS, not FAT.  (Or, just install and use Linux, perhaps in a VM.)  Read on for more painful ways to work with this stuff.

> P.S. Is there a way to check permissions in the Gitlab repository itself?

There is a way to inspect the permissions in each file in each commit, and to update them, even if you aren't using WSL.  It's a little bit painful though.

To understand how this works, let's start with how the Unix/Linux permissions themselves *really* work, on a real Linux/Unix file system.  There are three groupings of three "mode bits": `r`ead, `w`rite, and e`x`ecute are the mode bits, and `u`ser, `g`roup, and `o`ther are the groupings.

- A grouped-triple of `rwx` means that whoever *gets* this, has all three permissions on the underlying file: they can read, write, and execute the file.

  A grouped-triple of `---` means that whoever *gets* this has no permissions at all.
- Typically, the permissions are either `rw-` or `rwx` for the user: the file is readable and writable but not executable, or has full permissions.
- Typically, for most everyone else, the permissions are either `r--` or `r-x`: readable, but neither writable nor executable; or read-only.
- In between, members of a "group"—each file is owned by one user-ID and one group-ID—might be `r--` or `r-x`, meaning the group is treated like everyone not the user; or `rw-` or `rwx`, meaning the group is treated like the owner.  This group-ID stuff has limited usefulness: most modern systems use [ACLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) instead.  But this explains the Git modes, so it's worth mentioning.

These three groups of three permissions get presented in the order: `u`ser (the file's owner), `g`roup, and `o`ther.  (Note: `o` for `owner` would make more sense here, but `o` got used for `other`, so this became `u` for `user`.)  Hence files are most typically either `rw-r--r--`, meaning read/write for the user but read-only for everyone else, or `rwxr-xr-x`, meaning read/write/execute for the user, but read-and-execute-only for everyone else.

Now, here is the tricky bit: the three groups of bits get expressed in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), or base-8 notation, with bit 2 (value 4) representing the `r` bit, bit 1 (value 2) representing the `w` bit, and bit 0 (value 1) representing the `x` bit.  So for file whose `u`ser permissions are `rwx`, the value is 7 (4+2+1); for one whose `u`ser permissions are `rw-`, the value is 6 (4+2).  For a file whose `g`roup permissions are `r-x`, the value is 5 (4+1); for `r--`, it is 4.  For a file whose `o`ther permissions are `r-x`, the value is again 5, and for `r--` it is again 4`.

When we put these together, in this order, we get:

```
755 (rwxr-xr-x)
644 (rw-r--r--)
```

These are the two *most common* numbers found in [`lstat` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) results, on a Linux/Unix-style file system, for the permission bits.<sup>1</sup>  But any combination is *technically possible:* a user can set up their files so that only *everyone else* can read and write them, for instance (`---rw-rw-` or `066`).  This is not very sensible, but it is allowed.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that for a *directory*, read permission means that you can *list the names* in the directory, while execute permission means that you can *use* the name in the directory, to try to `lstat` or `open` the file for instance.  Hence directories that lack execute permission are frustrating: you can see the names in them, but never open any of those files, regardless of *their* permissions!  This particular quirk has a weird and sometimes useful effect in certain security models, but mount points allow users to bypass the quirk, so one must be very careful when trying to *use* this model.

---

#### So what does all this have to do with Git?

When Linus Torvalds *wrote* Git initially, he decided to support exactly this model for the permissions for each file *in* a Git commit.  Git's index therefore stores, for each file, a *mode*, as one of several possible numbers, usually expressed in octal.  The mode has a few extra higher-order bits that distinguish between regular files (mode `100xxx`) and symbolic links (mode `120xxx`), which he copied directly from the internal Unix/Linux model as well.

This let you store files that, when checked out, couldn't be used by yourself, only by everyone else (`mode 100066` for instance) since Git would create the files with that exact mode: `066` or `---rw-rw-`.  As already noted, this is basically useless in the file system; it also turned out to be useless *and harmful* in Git, so Git was modified, before the initial 1.0 release I think—certainly before Git 1.5—to prohibit this.  The only modes allowed *now* for regular files are `100644`, or `rw-r--r--`, and `100755`, or `rwx-r-xr-x`.  But the weird numbering still shows up.

If you run `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, for instance, to see how the files in the `HEAD` commit are stored, you will see these very same numbers.  Here are some of the files in a commit in the Git repository for Git:

```
...
100644 blob 311841f9bed577151a81f87174ccdd6939aa3eee    .gitignore
100644 blob cbeebdab7a5e2c6afec338c3534930f569c90f63    .gitmodules
...
100755 blob 9c125f298aea6863a9370c16a0f70b7cccc73b2d    GIT-VERSION-GEN
100644 blob 66389ce05915d776e5c8ff49aea40e20bc40eb62    INSTALL
100644 blob d38b1b92bdb2893eb4505667375563f2d6d4086b    LGPL-2.1
100644 blob c3565fc0f8f7df81232deca663bf55e14737ae97    Makefile
```

Note the `100755` in the middle here: that's an *executable* file.  The remaining files are all `100644`, i.e., *non-executable*.  These mode strings are literally how Git stores the `X` permissions, and you can see them directly in any existing commit, using `git ls-tree` (remember to use `-r` and a commit hash ID; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) for more about this).

Now, this only shows the modes of files stored *in commits*.  The mode for a file that's *not yet in a commit* is stored in Git's *index* (aka staging area, aka cache).  To see *these* entries, use [the `git ls-files` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files), with the `--stage` or `-s` option (two spellings for the same thing).  This, too, prints out the mode: `100644` or `100755`.

**The mode entry in the staging entry determines what will be in the *next* commit.**  The actual mode of the file in your own file system is *not relevant*.  However, the `git add` command can *change the mode* stored in the staging area.

#### How `git add` affects the staging mode

When you run `git add file`, or `git add -u`, or `git add .`, or whatever, Git will update the *index copy* of each file to match the *working tree* copy of that file.  This gets a little bit complicated:

- First, suppose the file is *deleted from the file system*.  In this case, `git add` also *deletes the file from the index*.  Everything else becomes irrelevant.  But if not, we go on to maybe update the file's mode.
- Suppose that `core.filemode` (or `core.fileMode`) is `true`.  Then Git *looks at* the mode as reported by the `lstat` system call.  If that mode has any `x` bits set, Git will set the *index's* mode to `100755`.  Otherwise, Git will set the *index's* mode to `100644`.

This relies on your `lstat` system call reporting the executable permissions correctly.  If your `lstat` system call *doesn't* report correctly, you should have `core.filemode` set to `false`.  Git now *ignores* the `lstat` mode results: the mode of the entry in the index remains unchanged.  Whatever `git ls-files --stage` said before, that's still the mode.

#### Manually updating modes when your file system does not coöperate

Should you wish to *change* the mode, you have two options:

- `git add --chmod=...` will update the index from your working tree copy *and* set the mode you specify.  This overrides the `lstat` result, and also overrides `core.filemode`.
- `git update-index` will let you override the mode.  There are numerous ways to do this with `git update-index`; the one that *only* overrides the mode is `git update-index --chmod=...`.

The argument to the `--chmod` command option should be either `+x` or `-x`.  The `+x` option means *set the mode to `100755`* and the `-x` option means *set the mode to `100644`*.

#### A final note about `core.filemode`

Whenever you *create a new repository*, Git will *probe the file system to see how it behaves*.  The precise way that Git does this is a bit peculiar, but essentially, it tries to see whether `chmod`s that set and remove executable-ness on a file-system file will "stick", i.e., be reflected back by a later `lstat` system call.  If they will, Git sets `core.filemode` to `true` for you.  If they won't, Git sets `core.filemode` to `false` for you.  **This ensures that Git behaves correctly.**

If you override this `core.filemode` setting, Git may begin behaving strangely.  If you *do* change this setting, be sure you understand all of the above.